# Mac freezes for a split-second, whenever I'm pressing CapsLock (Escape). How to reset input devices without rebooting?

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, freeze

**TL;DR:** How do I reboot my keyboard input device? Or reload the drivers? Obviously, a permanent solution to this would be awesome. But I'm trying to find a way to get past this, without having to restart my computer.

---

On my Mac from 2019, I have mapped CapsLock to Escape (in System Settings >> Keyboard >> Modifier Keys). And I'm using it quite a lot, since I'm using Vim a lot (lots of 'Escape's).

But there is this wierd bug, where if I press CapsLock, then the whole system freezes for half a second.
What's super-wierd is, that the bug isn't there if I just press the regular <kbd>Esc</kbd>-key - it's only the CapsLock-key that triggers the freeze.

It's super-annoying, since when in my IDE (with Vim-mode), when I press <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd>  (wanting to escape input-mode and go down 3 lines, then it jumps and then skips down 3 lines in one go.

I thought that it was just my IDE being wierd, but I noticed that if I put on a video on another screen, then it does that same same little 'jump', every time I press <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> (Escape).

A simple reboot of my computer does the job. I also tried reseting the NVRAM (restart and hold down <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd>), and that also fixes it (then). But it comes back on a regular basis. It started occuring 10 days ago, and has happend 4 times now.

Can I somehow restart / reset my input device, without having to restart my entire computer?
Or can I output somehow, what application/process 'locks'/'freezes' my computer on a certain point in time?

---

### Other info + solution attempts

- It occurs both on my external keyboard and on the built-in one (exactly same bug).
- I have two offices, and it has happend on both external keyboards (in either office), so it must be some system-wide stuff.
- I have tried quitting all applications, so it was only my IDE and my browser being open, and it still happens.
- OS-version: 11.5.1 (Big Sur)
- If I'm in a browser an simply scroll down. And while the browser is in motion, press the CapsLock-key, then it jerks for a second as well. This doesn't happen if I simply click the escape-button.

Comment: Somebody wrote that they had the same problem. They didn't have enough reputation to write it as a comment, so they wrote it as an answer (which has now been removed). So I'm not the only one.

Comment: Try to [reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295). See also [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81234/linux-on-mac-hardware-how-to-remove-caps-lock-delay-on-apple-macbook-pro-alumin), where in addition to the other answers, the poster used the solution of remapping the CapsLock key to another key, which solved his problem. The remap solution also comes up in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4068/caps-lock-key-response-delay-on-apple-wireless-keyboard).

Comment: How did you re-map your key? Is it configurable? Maybe it acts as an "EscLock-key" for a second every time you use it? Could you try using another tool to re-map keys to check if that fixes your problem?